# visual studio code real time live preview

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code, real-time, adobe-brackets, live-preview

We have been using Brackets editor for our front-end development tasks. One thing that we really like is the real-time live preview changes as we type the code in the editor. Recently we decided to look into React framework. We have checked out the Visual Studio Code, and Atom as an alternative to Brackets. But we really cannot find the real-time live preview feature from Brackets in any of these editors. And yes! we did check out the extensions/packages. Unfortunately none works as we wanted. Are we missing something? Any suggestions are appreciated.

B

Comment: You probably saw this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer  But it only works for html and css changes, not javascript.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, it does not work well when we did responsive coding.

Comment: Try [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68233569/836330 for a Live Preview extension written by the vscode team.