# See HTML preview on side tab in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

How can I see the HTML code live preview on the side tab in the VSCode editor?

end result I want:
[image]

**CSS, js, PHP, etc** should also work in the preview.

Comment: You can download and install the Live Server extension?

Answer (score 37):

The Vscode team has developed a `Live Server` extension with a lot of coordination with vscode.  See [v1.58 pre-release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#live-preview):

---

#### Live Preview

We have developed a Live Preview extension, which hosts a local server for web development previewing!

It features an in-editor browser preview, live preview refreshing (on file change or on save), multi-root support, and more!

[image: live preview 1]

---

The extension also has a `Live Preview` task, which runs a persistent server and allows you to view server traffic and its associated files.

[image: live preview 2]

To learn more about what it can do, [view it in the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server) or [check out its repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-livepreview).

---

[image: open preview button]

Comment: thanks , i wanted confirm will this also show react / threejs previews etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of different vscode extensions for browser previews.
The one i'm using is [Browser Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=auchenberg.vscode-browser-preview).

[image]

To view `.php` files, you need a server, like `Apache`.
**XAMPP** is an all in one solution which offers MySQL, Apache and some other tools: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Answer (score -2):

[ty4z's HTML Preview Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ty4z2008.html-preview) is pretty good:

[image]

JS and CSS definitely work in its preview window, but I haven't tested PHP yet.  My guess is it also probably works since the other two do.